# unable to find main.dart and lib folder from imported flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, project, program-entry-point

> hi there!
> i backed up my flutter project folder due to some issues with my drive,
> i fixed the issues
> only for me to try importing the project and continuing my work
> and it turns out i can't find my main.dart file along with my entire lib folder
> the only recognizable thing left in the project seems to be the assets folder

help me, please
this has really pushed me way behind schedule

also I would be much grateful if i could get an app that decompiles flutter apks
as my code is still in debug mode and i have the apk file.

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSGxN.png)

Comment: In the file explorer, do you see the lib folder?

Comment: **no not really**

Comment: Sorry bro..then it's not possible.

Comment: Please check hidden files once..also..if they were present before in that directory, and you DELETED them, you can use some recovery tools to recover them

Comment: Is there a way I can extract it from the apk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get source code of your apk file(debug) :-

Step 1- download strings for Windows (in your case)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings

Step 2-
Since kernel_blob.bin has all your app's source code,
Run this command,

```
strings /path/to/extracted/apk/assets/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin > extracted_code.dart
```

Here, replace, "path to extracted" to your own path.

Step 3

You’ll need to clean the extract_code file, and strings like “dart”, “import”, “void” and other keywords in ‘extracted_code.dart’, will help you find the code itself.(search for them to get your code)

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)